# How much is it to process 4M scientific papers in Microsoft Text Analytics for Health?

Tags: azure, entity

I would like to obtain Entities for the text in 4M scientific papers and want to know what would be the very rough approximate cost.

Comment: azure has billing support which is included in all tiers. try talking to them

Answer (score 1):

> Text Analytics for health is one of the prebuilt features offered by Azure Cognitive Service for Language.
>
> -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/text-analytics-for-health/overview

You can calculate a price estimate for Text Analytics for Health through the [Azure Pricing Calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/calculator/) - see the screenshot below.

[image]